# setting up freedns with an existing domain

Tags: subdomain, domain-registration, dynamic-dns

I've been running a webserver off of a pc at a static IP successfully for the past 5 months.

recently however, I've moved into another apartment and my ISP only provides a dynamic IP (my IP changes from time to time).

I'm not an internet genius but I was thinking to fix this by using a Dynamic DNS provider. So I got on the web and found [freedns](http://freedns.afraid.org).

I'm a bit confused about how to set up everything though.
I've managed to succesfully install the IP updater daemon on my web server.

Then, in my registrars control panel, I set the `NS` records to point at `ns1` through `ns4.afraid.org` (removing the old `NS` records).

I'm not certain what I should do with the `A` records though (for now they are still pointing to the old static IP address). I have `A` records for `www`, `blog`, `irc`, etc.
but I cannot point them at my new IP address, because it isn't

Could someone explain this in the clearest possible sense (perhaps elaborating on what happens at each step of the DNS process). I never really knew what the `A` records are for anyway.

*(note that I haven't really found any documentation at [the freedns website](http://freedns.afraid.org), or on google)*